# how to convert django admin default pagination to ajax pagination

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-pagination

I want to convert django admin listing pagination in to ajax pagination. is there django app avaialble in which admin functionality work on ajax

Answer (score 0):

Not that Im aware of. You will need to write a custom admin template and views to reflect this functionality.

You can copy the contents of `site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/change_list.html` to a custom template and exchange the following code with your custom page-handling:

```
{% block result_list %}
          {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
          {% result_list cl %}
          {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}
```

Make sure to set the new custom templates correctly. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) for more information.